# If a class is loaded multiple times, do its static-members get initialized multiple times?

Tags: java, initialization, classloader

If a class is loaded multiple times, do its static-members get initialized multiple times?
How do I check for that?

Comment: Why would you load a class multiple times?  Would that be via different class loaders?

Comment: Yes, different class loaders.

Comment: But why are you doing this?

Comment: As to they "why", that's my question too! Basically we have reasons to believe a class in our system is being loaded more than once. And we want to know if the fields would be re-initted

Comment: What if you analyse the classloader object of the class, as provided by http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getClassLoader()

Answer (score 6):

If there are different classloaders involved, then they will be completely separate classes, with separate static fields etc - and each will be initialized separately.

(The simplest way to diagnose this is just to log when you get initialized, of course...)

```
static {
    // Log initialization
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I did.

Comment: We put a static block in the class and do "printLn", only one println gets executed, but at one instance, we do see TWO different class objects of the class, calling `getClassLoader()` on  which returns two different values.

Comment: @OneTwoThree: Then you should see two log entries... are you sure one of them isn't writing to a log that is lost for some reason? (Another option is to have a static field which retains the time at which it was initialized. That might help.)

Comment: I've tried that. And I could've sworn the block is ONLY EXECUTED ONCE.

Comment: @OneTwoThree: Then I suspect your diagnosis of "two different class objects" is failing somehow. We can't really say any more based on just what you've told us...

Comment: Ok, I think I've got some clue. Maybe it's due to the fact that static members (and static blocks) are NOT initted when the class is loaded? (ie., only when the class is "used")

Comment: @OneTwoThree: Well, they're executed when the class is *initialized*. If you've got a class which has been loaded (e.g. by reflection) but nothing's using it yet, that could be the case...

Comment: @OneTwoThree: So the important thing is that by the time you actually start using it, it *will* be fully initialized.

Answer (score 3):

The code inside static block is executed only once: the first time you make an object of that class or the first time you access a static member of that class (even if you never make an object of that class). This mean its invoked when the class loader loads the class to memory. So its per class loader. If you have multiple class loaders each one will have its own copy of the classes so static block will be invoked by each class loaders. To test this you can put a Sysout in a static block an try and load it using a custom class loader. In the below example the static block will be executed twice. One by the system class loader when we run the static main method and then by our custom class loader.

```
package sample;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Sample {

    static {
        System.out.println("Entered Static Block!!");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CustomClassLoader loader = new CustomClassLoader();
        try {
            Class<?> c = loader.findClass("sample.Sample");
            Object o = c.newInstance();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

class CustomClassLoader extends ClassLoader {

    private Map<String, Class<?>> classes = new HashMap<String, Class<?>>();

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return CustomClassLoader.class.getName();
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?> findClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {

        if (classes.containsKey(name)) {
            return classes.get(name);
        }

        byte[] classData;

        try {
            classData = loadClassData(name);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new ClassNotFoundException("Class [" + name
                    + "] could not be found", e);
        }

        Class<?> c = defineClass(name, classData, 0, classData.length);
        resolveClass(c);
        classes.put(name, c);

        return c;
    }

    private byte[] loadClassData(String name) throws IOException {
        BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(
                ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream(name.replace(".", "/")
                        + ".class"));
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        int i;

        while ((i = in.read()) != -1) {
            out.write(i);
        }

        in.close();
        byte[] classData = out.toByteArray();
        out.close();

        return classData;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The following actions do *not* cause a class to be loaded:

- Referring to a static final primitive field that is known at compile time.
- `classLoader.getResource(className.replace('.', '/') + ".class")`

The following cause a class to be [**loaded**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.3) (i.e., the .class file is parsed, and a `Class<?>` object is created):

- Any line of code that refers to the class symbolically e.g. `Foo.class`
- Class.forName(String, *false*, ClassLoader)
- ClassLoader.loadClass(String)
- Loading a subclass or array of the class, or initializing a class whose code or method signatures refer to the class.

The following cause a class to be [**initialized**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.5) (i.e., the static blocks are executed):

- Constructing a new instance
- Calling a static method
- Getting or setting a static field that is not a compile-time constant.
- Class.forName(String, *true*, ClassLoader) and Class.forName(String)

If you do initialize the class from multiple ClassLoaders, the static blocks are indeed executed multiple times. For example, the following code:

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLClassLoader;

public class InitializeClassMultipleTimes {
    static class Foo {
        static {
            System.out.format("  %s initialized by %s%n", Foo.class.getSimpleName(), Foo.class.getClassLoader());
        }
        public static void foo() {}
    }
    private static Class<Foo> loadClass() {
        System.out.println("Loading class.");
        // Load the .class file. This will fail if the class file is gone or has
        // the wrong file format.
        return Foo.class;
    }
    private static void initializeClass(Class<?> innerClass) {
        System.out.println("Initializing class");
        try {
            Class.forName(innerClass.getName(), true, innerClass.getClassLoader());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String... argv) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        Class<Foo> fooClass = loadClass();
        initializeClass(fooClass);

        URLClassLoader myClassLoader = ((URLClassLoader) InitializeClassMultipleTimes.class.getClassLoader());
        URL[] urls = myClassLoader.getURLs();
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            URLClassLoader newClassLoader = new URLClassLoader(urls, null);  // parent=bootstrap
            System.out.format("%nLoading class using another class loader%n", Foo.class.getSimpleName());
            Class<?> fooClassAgain = Class.forName(fooClass.getName(), false, newClassLoader);
            initializeClass(fooClassAgain);
        }
    }
}
```

produces the following output. Note that you can also run it under `strace -f -e file` to verify when the .class files are read.

```
Loading class.
Initializing class
  Foo initialized by sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@73d16e93

Loading class using another class loader
Initializing class
  Foo initialized by java.net.URLClassLoader@15db9742

Loading class using another class loader
Initializing class
  Foo initialized by java.net.URLClassLoader@7852e922
```